# inherit xib-file in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `ViewController.xib` made in IB, that has a `UITableView`.
I want to build another xib-file e.g. `SearchViewController.xib`, thas inherit from `ViewController.xib`. The new SearchViewController.xib should inherit the `UITableView` and additionally it should have a `UISearchBar` and a `UIButton`.

It's possible to make this scenario with the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no concept of inheritance among NIB files. Your only option is to duplicate the original file and make the necessary changes in the copy.

Comment: As Ole said, there is no inheritance. You can and should inherit the controllers that handle views that share funcionality.

Comment: Also, it is possible to create xibs for specific view (although it's not as easy as it should be).

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of a Container View in order to reuse a particular view controller. That way you only have to create it once, add the logic once and you can simply reuse the component where-ever you like:

[image]

This is [Apples documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) on the Container View, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need separate .xib files or, use one as the default, then add the controls (e.g. SearchViewController, etc) programmatically in code.

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about it is that a XIB file is a serialised *object* and not a class. An instance of a class (i.e. an object) cannot be subclassed, except from some prototype based languages like Javascript.

One way of mocking this however is by creating a parent class of UIView type which will load the XIB and add it to itself (remember that a XIB contains an NSArray of visual elements).

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView* mainView = (UIView*)[nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
        self.label.text = @"Parent";
        [self addSubview:mainView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The Child can then simply override the initialiser as

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.label.text = @"Child";
    }
    return self;
}
```

The `self.label` is of course linked to a UILabel in the XIB file via interface builder and connected at runtime via the `owner:self` argument.

Comment: The best answer here, frankly.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a problem should be taken care of in xCode's next versions .As you need to write in code your interface needed to be inherited in other classes which is a nightmare in case of modifications are required later .Or you can copy/paste xib file which will be also a nightmare as you'll need to open them all and apply modifications

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that subclass calls initWithNibName with it's class name.

I would go with forcing superclass to load the superclass xib always even if inherited (make sure that outlets are in .h of the super class)

in superclass override initWithNib (it will be called as well as normal init if you created xib based vc)

```
-(instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"NameOfTheSuperClass" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```