# How to inherit a XIB file in an iOS project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a custom table cell inherited from UITableViewCell. It's working fine.

Now I have to make same kind of cell for some other screen with little modifications. What I was planning that I shall inherit my old cell class to reuse its design and logic, but I couldn't find a way how to inherit a xib file.

Should I copy/paste all views from one xib to other or is there a way to extend it with few changes?

EDIT: I have read the following questions and they claim that its not possible right now:

- [IOS inherit a UIViewController with xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468275/ios-inherit-a-uiviewcontroller-with-xib-file)
- [inherit xib-file in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418080/inherit-xib-file-in-interface-builder)

In case it's impossible, what approach should we use to do this effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You should duplicate the file and make necessary changes.

Thanks

Comment: While thinking in OO context, I was trying to avoid duplication;

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing the XIB editor can do that you cannot do programmatically. The easiest path is (typically) to just move it all over to code and then delete the XIB from all targets/projects. Then you can subclass however you like.

As a bonus, this can really simplify management of resources for your multiple targets.

An alternative to moving it over to code is to just move the modifiable portions to other instances (held/referenced by the cell). The controller could then set this attribute before presentation. So if the stylization and drawing in some regard were special or customizable, then just move that logic out to a class hierarchy which does not rely on the XIB deserialization and then make those portions properties of the cell you have defined in the nib.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some other solution for your problem, then I would suggest you to create a custom cell programmatically.

I am Explaining you step by step, this will help you better.

So for that create a class which inherit from `UITableViewCell`, and add components that you needed in your tabelCell.

**so your .h file looks like this.**

//--------START------->>

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell{

UIButton *btn1;
UIButton *btn2;
UIButton *btn3;

}

@property(nonatomic , retain) UIButton *btn1;
@property(nonatomic , retain) UIButton *btn2;
@property(nonatomic , retain) UIButton *btn3;

@end
```

//-------END------- <<

**and your .m file will look like this**

//--------START------->>

```
  #import "CustomCell.h"

  @implementation CustomCell
  @synthesize btn1, btn2, btn3;

  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
   {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    //----frame the components as per your project req.----       

    btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 85, 70)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:btn1];

    btn2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 1, 85, 70)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:btn2];

    btn3 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195,1, 85, 70)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:btn3];
   }
    return self;
   }

   - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
   {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

      // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
```

//--------END-------<<

Now you are ready to reuse this custom cell in your other classes. and also can modify them as per requirement.

**Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath >>**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell  *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

  [cell.btN1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE NAME"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // YOU CAN MAKE CHANGES HERE.

    ................// remaining logic goes here

 return cell;

 }
```

HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU.

[1 .Also take a look on link tutorial.](http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)

[2. A Closer Look at Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Comment: I think you didn't read my question; I have already a custom cell inherit from UITableViewCell class; I know how to make custom cells for tableView; I need one level more inheritance, not directly from UITableViewCell, but from my own custom cell class, and importantly to reuse xib file view;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just Subclassing the custom cell view class? That way you can have IBOutlets in the base class for all UI components and in the new subclass you can manage them as you want as per the new behaviour. It would be just like subclassing a UIView or a UIViewController etc.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once and What I did is:

Instead of subclassing I made a seperate `UIView` having table with customCell and added that view as subView where needed. I was able to change the UI of customCell with a **key** in customCell to know which `UIViewController` is adding it as a subView.

I am not sure how good this approach is, but still is a way :)