# Inherit ViewController from Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have a Storyboard named `CustomComponents.storyboard` and I had designed `BaseViewController` in Storyboard. For example, I set `backgroundColor` of `BaseViewController` to `.green` in Interface Builder. I inherit `RootViewController` from `BaseViewController`. I expect the `backgroundColor` of `RootViewController` to be `.green`.

This is my `RootViewController`

```
class RootViewController: BaseViewController {

}
```

and this is my `BaseViewController`

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

both the classes are empty and I have just set the `backgroundColor` in IB.

But, I see white background when I run the app. But, when the color is set programmatically in `BaseViewController`, green background colour is applied to `RootViewController` as expected.

What am I missing to inherit `BaseViewController` which is designed in Storyboard? Basically, I would like to design my `BaseViewController` in Storyboard. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you get the reference of BaseViewController??

Comment: Both are empty classes. I just inherit from `BaseViewController`

Comment: You need to instantiate the ViewController from the storyboard, or there is no way to see the changes from it. Imagine the Stroryboard as an instance of your BaseViewController, not as a definition of the class

Comment: Please Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419948/ios-swift-subclassing-viewcontroller-initialized-by-xib-nib-file && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418080/inherit-xib-file-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically only if your application min spec is iOS 13, because new API available for such purpose, because storyboard does not contain *a class* declaration it is archive of encoded instance

So if your `BaseViewController` has identifier, you can instantiate `RootViewController` with encoded parent as

```
let rootController = UIStoryboard(name: "CustomComponents", 
    bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: 
                             "your_base_controller_identifier_here") { coder in
        RootViewController(coder: coder)
}
```

or if your controller is root

```
let rootController = UIStoryboard(name: "CustomComponents", 
     bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController { coder in
        RootViewController(coder: coder)
}
```